# How does Ordering Nodes Synchronization work?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

How can adding a new orderer download the ledger as ordering nodes are not connected with each other and kafka keeps messages only for 7 days.

And also if I shut down a orderer node for more than 7 days and if I bring it up again then it will not find the transactions that happened in those 7 days in kafka partition therefore how will it sync and update it's local ledger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 1.0, Kafka brokers are to be set with `log.retention.ms = -1` (source: [documentation](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/ab38851497882ed1e0b5efe40ff541942d4cbecf/docs/source/kafka.rst#steps), Step 4e).

This disables time-based retention and prevents segments from expiring. This means that:

1. A partition hosts the entire transaction history of the channel.
2. A new orderer service node (OSN) can be added at any point in time and use the Kafka brokers to sync up with all channels in their entirety.

In a minor release within the 1.x track we will support ledger pruning for the OSNs. This means that the brokers will only need to maintain a pruned sequence of the transaction history (that will always start from a configuration block), and any *new* OSN will only be able to sync back to that configuration block.